# Common code for WinForms and ASP.NET custom control

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms, custom-controls

Suppose I want to develop a custom, purely graphical control to be used in both WinForms as well as ASP.NET. The control will, based on some property settings and associated rules, render an image.

Obviously, I could just duplicate the code from the WinForms version to the ASP.NET version, but that would mean that if an error is found, or a rule is changed, I have two versions to update.

I could write a core class, with the various properties and rules needed, and the WinForms and ASP.NET control classes will have a property pointing to this core class, something like:

```
public class MyControlCore
{
    // all properties and control rules

    public void PaintTo(Graphics graphics)
    {
        // rendering of control
    }
}

public class MyWinFormsControl: Control
{
    public MyWinFormsControl(Control parent): base(parent)
    {
        CoreControl = new MyControlCore();
    }

    public MyControlCore CoreControl { get; private set; }

    protected override OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        CoreControl.PaintTo(e.Graphics);
    }
}
```

This will work, but in the property grid I would get a property `CoreControl`, containing the customization properties. Is there a way to have the property grid show the `MyControlCore` properties, instead of the `CoreControl` property with the sub properties?

I was thinking that I could perhaps accomplish this with `TypeDescriptionProvider` and related classes, but I'm unsure how to proceed and if it would even give me the results I'm after. I realize this would only help me in the designer, but that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another choice. You could use [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and put the common code in a single file that you can link to from both projects.

Comment: Interesting. So I would create a file containing the partial class `MyControl`, with all the common stuff in it, en then in the WinForms project I create a class file and declare the same partial class, derive it from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, link the first file into the project, and then do the same for the ASP.NET control in another project. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Accepted your answer as it's a simpler and even more elegant approach of the problem. Thanks.